# stop variables being overwritten in NodeJS & Express

Tags: node.js

Okay so currently I've got a [ExpressJS](https://expressjs.com/) API that I've wrote that works alongside [Puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer) however if I send concurrent requests then if request 1 updates `device_imei` then request 2 will get that value instead of it's own state?

My script looks like so:

```
let proxy;
let recaptcha_solution;
let page;
let browser = false;
let device_imei;
let domains;
let token;
let userProfile;
let tokenRefId;
let requestNo;
let success = true;
let errorCode;
let emails;
let errorMessage;
let requestId;
let bitmap;
let validationId;

const handle_response = async (response) => {
    const url = response.url();
    try {
        const req = response.request();
        const orig = req.url();
        let status;
        let text;
        if(response.status) {
            status = response.status();
        }
        if(
            status
            && !(status > 299 && status < 400)
            && !(status === 204)
            && (req.resourceType() === 'xhr')
        ) {
            text = await response.text();
            if(text.includes('Access Denied')) {
                success = false;
                return;
            }
            const json = JSON.parse(text);
            if(json['reCaptchaDetail']) {
                if(json['reCaptchaDetail']['token'] && json['reCaptchaDetail']['tokenRefId']) {
                    token = json['reCaptchaDetail']['token'];
                    tokenRefId = json['reCaptchaDetail']['tokenRefId'];
                    await client.set('captcha_solution', JSON.stringify(json['reCaptchaDetail']), 'EX', 3600);
                }
            } else if(json['error']) {
                success = false;
                if(json['error']['errorId'].startsWith('UNLOCK')) {
                    errorCode = json['error']['details'][0]['code'];
                    errorMessage = json['error']['details'][0]['message'];
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(`Failed getting data from: ${url}`);
        console.error(err);
    }
};

const createOrder = async (req, res) => {
    let params = await parser.parseStringPromise(req.body.parameters);

    device_imei = params.PARAMETERS.IMEI;

    //config
    axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
    axios.defaults.timeout = 15000;
    userProfile = faker.entity.user();

    page = await browser.newPage();

    page.on('response', handle_response);

    //a lot more stuff that accesses/updates all the let vars and working with page var.
}

app.post('/api/index.php', async function (req, res) {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
    res.setHeader('X-Powered-By', 'DHRU-FUSION');
    res.setHeader('dhru-fusion-api-version', '6.1');
    res.removeHeader('pragma');
    res.removeHeader('server');
    res.removeHeader('transfer-encoding');
    res.removeHeader('cache-control');
    res.removeHeader('expires');

    if (Object.keys(req.body).length === 0) {
        return res.send(error_response('Invalid Request'));
    }

    if (typeof req.body.apiaccesskey === undefined || req.body.apiaccesskey !== process.env.SITE_API_KEY) {
        return res.send(error_response('Invalid API Key'));
    }

    switch(req.body.action) {
        case "placeimeiorder":
            createOrder(req, res).catch(function ignore() {});
            return res.send(success_response({
                'MESSAGE': 'Order Received!'
            }));
        default:
            return res.send(error_response('Invalid Action'));
    }
});

app.listen(3000);
```

Would I have to implement mutli-threading so my variables can maintain state? or is their a much easier solution?

Comment: You're asking two completely unrelated questions. The title asks how to "stop variables being overwritten" but your question makes no reference at all to any variables being overwritten and instead asks about the app freezing up when concurrent requests are sent. What actually is the issue?

Comment: @Klaycon I've updated my question, sorry for the confusion

Comment: Your variables are shared between requests.  You should make each request self-contained.   What exactly are you attempting and why do you need to store the device_imei between requests?

Comment: @JasonGoemaat it's not intentional, it's because I have other functions accessing this variable also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're having issues due to making all of your variables top-level, as if they're static or global. But really the variables each depend on a specific execution of your handler function, so they need to be declared in the function! If you're struggling with passing the variables to your `handle_response` function, I recommend containing them all into an object and passing that on. Something like this:

```
const handle_response = async (response, state) => {
    const url = response.url();
    try {
        const req = response.request();
        const orig = req.url();
        let status;
        let text;
        if(response.status) {
            status = response.status();
        }
        if(
            status
            && !(status > 299 && status < 400)
            && !(status === 204)
            && (req.resourceType() === 'xhr')
        ) {
            text = await response.text();
            if(text.includes('Access Denied')) {
                state.success = false;
                return;
            }
            const json = JSON.parse(text);
            if(json['reCaptchaDetail']) {
                if(json['reCaptchaDetail']['token'] && json['reCaptchaDetail']['tokenRefId']) {
                    state.token = json['reCaptchaDetail']['token'];
                    state.tokenRefId = json['reCaptchaDetail']['tokenRefId'];
                    await client.set('captcha_solution', JSON.stringify(json['reCaptchaDetail']), 'EX', 3600);
                }
            } else if(json['error']) {
                state.success = false;
                if(json['error']['errorId'].startsWith('UNLOCK')) {
                    state.errorCode = json['error']['details'][0]['code'];
                    state.errorMessage = json['error']['details'][0]['message'];
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(`Failed getting data from: ${url}`);
        console.error(err);
    }
};

const createOrder = async (req, res) => {
    let params = await parser.parseStringPromise(req.body.parameters);
    let state = {}; //put all your variables as properties of this object    

    state.device_imei = params.PARAMETERS.IMEI;

    //config
    axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
    axios.defaults.timeout = 15000;
    state.userProfile = faker.entity.user();

    let page = await browser.newPage(); //make things local if they dont need to be passed

    page.on('response', response => handle_response(response, state));

    //a lot more stuff that accesses/updates all the object properties and working with page var.
}
```

To reiterate: When building any asynchronous application, *absolutely do not reuse* the same global variables in your functions... as you've seen, it just leads to their values being overwritten by a concurrent request. Keep all your variables locally scoped to the scope of the request, and **pass them along** to any functions that need them.

Comment: Thankyou, however my current issue is that `createOrder` is reliant on information updated inside the `handle_response` how can I access the new stuff? as it's an event watcher? will the `response` var update each time?

Comment: @Curtis `createOrder`'s reference to `state` is the same one that gets passed to `handle_response`. So if `handle_response` updates anything in `state`, `createOrder` will be able to access those updated properties.